# How can i get this link element? Always show "Unable to find element with link text == Search"

Tags: javascript, c#

I am learning selenium with c# ,i am tring to click a link under a list ,but always show error "Unable to find element with link text == Search",code as below:

```
<div id="ctl00_subNavMain_upSubMenu">
    <ul id="ctl00_subNavMain_subMenu">
        <li class="btnHome selected">
            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$subNavMain$subMenu','0')">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="btnNew">
            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$subNavMain$subMenu','1')">New Observation</a>
        </li>
        <li class="btnTestPlatform">
            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$subNavMain$subMenu','2')">Test Platforms</a>
        </li>
        <li class="btnSearch">
            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$subNavMain$subMenu','3')">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li class="btnOTS">
            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$subNavMain$subMenu','4')">Remedy OTS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="btnBug">
            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$subNavMain$subMenu','5')">Bugzilla</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried this:

```
            ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'Search')]"));
            MessageBox.Show(links.Count.ToString());
            foreach (IWebElement link in links)
            {
                if(link.TagName=="a")
             {
                    //MessageBox.Show(link.Displayed.ToString());
                    link.Click();                  
            }                            
           }
```

but it shows error"this element can not be clicked" and i have tried use "link.Displayed",there are all false ,so how can i solve it ,it's a big problem for me,thanks!

I have tried this :" MessageBox.Show(link.Enabled.ToString());" all return"true"

solution:"javascriptexecuter js= (javascriptexecuter)driver; js.executescript("arguments[0]. click()",link);"
thanks all very much.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this in your find element as xpath:

//*[contains(text(),'Search')]

Comment: thanks,it works ,i find two elements ,and do link.Click(), but it shows error "Cannot click on element",i use "link.Displayed", all show false,do you know how to solve it ?thanks!

Comment: Try to use: 1.link.sendkeys("\n"). 2. Use javascript like this : javascriptexecuter js= (javascriptexecuter)driver; js.executescript("arguments[0]. click()",link);. 3. Actions a= new Actions(driver); a.click(link).build().perform()

Comment: thanks very much, I have tried these three methods,the second works,other pop up same error.thanks.

Comment: I can't understand. Is there more problems?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Hezi Israeli.
Unless you are looking for a string that is common to several elements, prefer to use 'contains' instead of '='. I have tested web-pages that have spaces before \ after specific words and this caused my xpaths that use '=' to fail. Using 'contains' protect you from that.

Comment: thanks,it works ,i find two elements ,and do link.Click(), but it shows error "Cannot click on element",i use "link.Displayed", all show false,do you know how to solve it ?thanks!